# How can i do multiple onClick animations in Styled components?

Tags: css, reactjs, button, react-hooks, styled-components

I have 2 buttons and i want to animate each one when clicked. The problem is that when the second button is clicked the animation restarts because of React re-rendering the document. How can i solve this? I am new to StyledComponents.

[Here is a codesandbox whit the problem.]
https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-joliot-v3mlf

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move style components out of function, and then pass props (`active` and `active2`) to style components.

Here is fork your example code, and do some modification:

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-curran-0bxf0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Oh I understand. Thank you very much alvin.